# Datepicker directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to use jQuery datepicker with textboxes created dynamically using AngularJS.

I created a directive to wrap my jQuery datepicker initialization so that I can use the datepicker.

Here is my directive

```
ERMApp.directive('angulardatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                scope.date = date;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

When I use my directive like this it works perfectly.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mydate" angulardatepicker />
```

However, when my textboxes are inside ng-repeat, then I can see the datepicker on each textbox but the models are not updated.

```
<div ng-repeat="term in terms">

    <input type="text" ng-model="term.mydate" angulardatepicker />

</div>
```

Always I am getting term.mydate = null . **The datepicker is showing but the selected date is not reflected in the model**

Comment: Did you check `term.date` variable value, because that's what you're assigning your dates to...

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be:

```
onSelect: function (date) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
    });
}
```

Additionally you should take care to move the model value to the view, overriding `$render`, e.g. as:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    ...
    ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
        element.datepicker('setDate', ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
    };
}
```

This assumes that the view value of the model is of type `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You're somehow misunderstanding AngularJS directives as you're trying to read `mydate` value but you're writing to `scope.date` variable. But to correctly set `ng-model` value you should rather use `ngModelController`'s functions that will set value to correct model property set by `ng-model` HTML attribute

This is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/hugalomomi/1/) of what you're likely trying to do.

Directive's configuration object is a bit different to yours:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd.m.yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                // mind the difference in setting model value
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
            }
        });
    }
};
```